# Inherit logger name in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to log the uncaught exception in python. For that, I am setting the `sys.excepthook` in my `__init__.py` as follows.

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback


def log_except_hook(*exc_info):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    text = "".join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info))
    logger.critical(f"Unhandled exception:\n{text}")


sys.excepthook = log_except_hook
```

My problem is that when I run a process and an exception occurs, the module name in the logged exception is the name of the folder containing the code (`src` in this case), instead of the name of the function in which it occurred (`foo_produce_an_error` in this example). Please find an example below:

```
2019-10-09 18:55:48,638 src CRITICAL: Unhandled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ivallesp/Projects/Project_Folder/main.py", line 109, in <module>
    foo_function(7)
  File "/Users/ivallesp/Projects/Project_Folder/src/new_module.py", line 8, in foo_function
    foo_produce_an_error(x)
  File "/Users/ivallesp/Projects/Project_Folder/src/new_module.py", line 12, in foo_produce_an_error
    x / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

How can I make logging to show the module and name of the function where the error ocurred in the first logging line?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided enough information to answer the question - for example, how you've configured logging (specifically, the format string/formatter used). I can illustrate how to achieve the desired result in general, with an example. Suppose you have a failing function in a module `failfunc`:

```
# failfunc.py
def the_failing_func():
    1 / 0
```

Then, your main script might be:

```
# logtest_ue.py
import logging
import sys

from failfunc import the_failing_func

def log_except_hook(*exc_info):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    tb = exc_info[-1]
    # get the bottom-most traceback entry
    while tb.tb_next:
        tb = tb.tb_next
    modname = tb.tb_frame.f_globals.get('__name__')
    funcname = tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
    logger.critical('Unhandled in module %r, function %r: %s',
                    modname, funcname, exc_info[1], exc_info=exc_info)

sys.excepthook = log_except_hook

def main():
    the_failing_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s %(message)s')
    sys.exit(main())
```

when this is run, it prints

```
CRITICAL Unhandled in module 'failfunc', function 'the_failing_func': division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logtest_ue.py", line 23, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "logtest_ue.py", line 19, in main
    the_failing_func()
  File "/home/vinay/projects/scratch/failfunc.py", line 2, in the_failing_func
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Note the slightly simpler way of getting a traceback into the log, using the `exc_info` keyword parameter. Also note that in this case, the normal module and function name (which could be displayed using `%(module)s` and `%(funcName)s` in a format string) would be those where the `sys.excepthook` points to, not the values where the exception actually occurred. For those, you would have to use the traceback object in the way I've illustrated to get the bottom-most frame (where the exception actually occurred) and get the module and function names from that frame.

Answer (score 1):

The module is hard to get but you can have filename and line number. They are contained in exc_info which you don't need to format yourself. You can just pass them to the log function and use a formatter to display it all. Here's an example code to give you an idea how this is done:

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback


def log_except_hook(*exc_info):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(fname)s:%(lnum)s %(message)s %(exc_info)s'))
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    frame = traceback.extract_tb(exc_info[2])[-1]
    fname = frame.filename
    lnum = frame.lineno
    logger.critical("Unhandled exception:", exc_info=exc_info, extra={'fname':fname, 'lnum':lnum})

sys.excepthook = log_except_hook
```